# Tool for Querying data at Runtime with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, runtime

The more and more I use the LINQ the more and more I really enjoy it, and it's syntax. I do a lot of data comparisons on a day to day basis. What I would really enjoy is a tool that allows me to load a DataSet, and then query that DataSet at runtime with LINQ queries. I primarily just want a tool, and to be able to load my DataSets dynamically.

Does something like this exist? I don't think LINQ was originally intended for this type of use, but I feel like it would be a powerful tool to have if it existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean to be honest... but [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/) allows you to load data and then query it.

Strongly-typed datasets are already easy to query with LINQ; weakly typed ones are a bit more of a pain, but [LINQ to DataSet](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/linq-to-dataset.aspx) makes it easier than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, my terminology is not always the best. It looks like LINQPad is probably what I was asking for. How could I have asked it better?

Comment: w00t w00t for LinqPad. Essential toolage.

Comment: @jsmith: You could have made it clear whether you wanted to load the *dataset* dynamically but use a pre-canned query, and whether this needed to be code within your own app or whether you were just looking for a tool.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out LinqPad http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the tool is called [`DataTable.AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I must have asked the question wrong. This answer is probably right because of my terminology, but nonetheless, your answer feels like sarcasm.

Comment: Sorry right back, I guess I just didn't understand.  LINQPad doesn't really have anything to do with `DataSets` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ with the specification/filter pattern to create dynamically generated queries. There's a LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-NHibernate implementation on [Github](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon).